# Is there any way to fetch the username and server from env file in shell script for SFTP

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

i am using sftp command in bash file,

```
sftp myname@server<<EOF
```

I wanted to take these values from the one of the like,

```
server = servername ; export server
```

how to use this value in the  sftp command,

```
sftp %myname@%server<<EOF
```

i am getting error that hostname could not be resolved.

could anyone please suggest how to resolve the same.

Comment: Bash, or batch? `%myname` is Windows batch syntax; _bash_ uses dollar signs for parameter expansion; so `sftp "${myname}@${server}" <<EOF`.

Comment: (also, `server = servername` isn't valid bash syntax either; it would need to be `server=servername` without the spaces).

Comment: (Huh; it's tricky to find a duplicate for this -- we have lots of harder questions already in the knowledgebase, like "how do I dereference a variable with another variable's name?", but the easy ones like "how do I use a variable in bash?" are hard to find, should they exist).

Comment: @Helen : Where did you get this funny syntax from? Please always post your complete script, at least to the extent that we know what you are actually doing. The snippets you posted here don't make much sense to me. For debugging, you may want to run your script with `-x`, so that you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
# if these lines are in a file, ". filename" will set them in the current shell
myname=userNameGoesHere
server=host.example.com

sftp "${myname}@${server}" <<EOF
...commands here...
EOF
```